# Why is there no language supporting a if..elseif..any..else construction?

Tags: language-design

Not for the first time, I wanted to do something like this:

```
if condition1
  result1
elseif condition2
  result2
else
  result3
else result4, so 'if result3 did not run' then run result4.
```

But this does not exist. One could nest the ifs or use additional variables, but both are more complicated to write and read. Instead, my suggested solution to this problem would be a language construct like this:

```
if condition1
  result1
elseif condition2
  result2
any
  result4
else
  result3
```

Which would work for any number of elseifs.

This is new so people will have to learn it, but many languages have non-standard things, like Ruby's `obj.each do |item|`, Python's `except ... else`, or Java's `"string" != "string"`. Reading this construct for the first time without introduction, one may or may not get it straight away, but it's not a terribly difficult concept to grasp or search for. I also don't see any technical problems such as ambiguity that would prevent it from being implemented.

Am I missing any reason why this could not be implemented, or why this should not be implemented? (Those are two separate questions.)

Comment: and just adding result4 after result1 and result2 is not an option?

Comment: @ratchetfreak it would work, but I don't like it because it violates DRY

Comment: Any implys to me if any of the branches run, not any but the one without any conditions. How often does this come up, why is that else branch so special?

Comment: This is a highly confusing construct which you would suggest adding in place of the currently clear and concise solutions to the same situation. Also, how you imagine not nesting something in a confusing location to "violate DRY" is altogether unclear. I would say this doesn't exist because it's beyond strange and any language designer would just throw the idea out off-hand as bad design.

Comment: It feels like the result3 is actually some kind of error handling rather than a full fledged condition. Why not early return if it happens.

Comment: I would suggest a reading of [Minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) and Eric Lippert's [The Future of C#, Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/10/08/the-future-of-c-part-one/).  Features have costs. This one doesn't likely have sufficient ROI.

Comment: @MichaelT Good one, I read that before (I remembered after the first sentence) but hadn't thought of this in that way. I guess that does answer my question.

Comment: I must have read this a dozen times and I still don't see where such a construct would be useful. Do you have a real life example?

Comment: The answer to all "Why didn't they put [this] in a programming language" questions is "because the costs exceeded the benefits."

Comment: I find this question interesting. But I wouldn't add this `any` syntactic sugar to a language because it doesn't seem to be really worth it. It's just an additional keyword for something that can easily be solved in various ways.

Comment: A concrete real-world example would help... I honestly don't understand the question :( oh, I think I got it: you want a case for when both conditions hold?)

Comment: @RobbieDee, here is a slightly fleshed out example: https://gist.github.com/winstonewert/4e176f150cbc627ac4b8

Comment: May I suggest when proposing new control structures that you always include an example of the desired semantics using current syntax and not just psuedocode? Its crazy confusing when you use natural language psuedocode to describe what you want.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: I appreciate the gist since it made me understand the proposal better. But I don't find it very meaningful to just print "I did it" in the `any`-clause, so the example doesn't convince me of the real-world use case for the clause. More likely such a block would throw an exception or return an error code in the case of an unsupported OS, in which case an `any`-clause would be less useful.

Comment: @JacquesB, true printing "I did it" wouldn't be meaningful. I could see logging the fact that a task was done, which was what I had in mind. Nevertheless, I agree that in almost every case I can see, I'd throw an exception/return an error code in the else case making it less useful.

Comment: Do you only allow one 'any' or multiple? Each applies to if/elseifs immediately above it, not below? I am warming up to the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every language feature has a cost to it. It could be a cost of added complexity to the parser. It could be an opportunity cost at *not* implementing some other language feature. It could be the cost of having developers work on it. It could be a cost of additional testing and possible backwards incompatibility. It could be the cost of future "why did we add this?" discussions when it causes a conflict with some other desired feature.

Whatever the case, there is a cost for every feature that is put into the language.  And thus, there is a return on investment too - did the cost we sunk into the feature improve the language for the people who use it more than some other feature and its cost that we *didn't* do.

In [Eric Gunnerson's Minus 100 points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericgu/minus-100-points), he describes the process of the language development for C#.

> So, we decided on the additive approach instead, and worked hard to keep the complexity down. One way to do that is through the concept of “minus 100 points”. Every feature starts out in the hole by 100 points, which means that it has to have a significant net positive effect on the overall package for it to make it into the language. Some features are okay features for a language to have, they just aren't quite good enough to make it into the language.

And in [Eric Lippert's The Future of C#, Part One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-future-of-c-part-one)

> After we finished the last-minute minor redesigns of various parts of C# 3.0, we made a list of every feature we could think of that could possibly go into a future version of C#. We spent many, many hours going through each feature on that list, trying to “bucket” it. Each feature got put into a unique bucket. The buckets were labelled:

> Pri 1: Must have in the next version
> Pri 2: Should have in the next version
> Pri 3: Nice to have in the next version
> Pri 4: Likely requires deep study for many years before we can do it
> Pri 5: Bad idea

> Obviously we immediately stopped considering the fours and fives in the context of the next version. We then added up the costs of the features in the first three buckets, compared them against the design, implementation, testing and documenting resources we had available. The costs were massively higher than the resources available, so we cut everything in bucket 2 and 3, and about half of what was in bucket 1. Turns out that some of those “must haves” were actually “should haves”.

> Understanding this bucketing process will help when I talk about some of the features suggested in that long forum topic. Many of the features suggested were perfectly good, but fell into bucket 3. They didn’t make up the 100 point deficit, they just weren’t compelling enough.

While this isn't necessarily the process for all languages, it is what likely goes on in many minds.  Having everything and the kitchen sink isn't a good design (look at php for examples of this).  A small language, with fewer features is often easier to reason about, write, and extend. To add a feature it really needs to have a compelling reason that can overcome that 100 point deficit for the additional complexity to be added and cost to be paid.

Its not that this is a good idea, or a bad idea... its just that there are a *lot* of good ideas out there.

Comment: Aside, Swift has a rather open (compared to other languages I've seen) proposal process which can be watched at [apple/swift-evolution](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution) on GitHub.

Answer (score 13):

Because this is a corner case *at best*.

Why add complexity to the language for something few people would ever use, and would use rarely even then?

Comment: Indeed, marking the else branch out as special seems bizarre, is the if branch special too?

Comment: If this is a corner case, the whole `elif`, `elsif` or `elseif` constructions are even more unnecessary when `else if` works just fine. What I am proposing makes an actual use case easier. I don't know about others, but I come across this regularly enough that I started discussing it with people.

Comment: @Luc The reason why elif, elsif, elseif existed was because they didn't introduce extra nesting. They often had an endif keyword at the end so a lonf else if chain would need as many endifs as there were ifs. The construct elseif removed that annoyance.

Comment: To be quite honest, I'm with the OP here. The proposed feature is equivalent in intention to Python's `for... else...` (and similar, if inverted, to `try..catch..finally`) and I for one would like to see it implemented.

Comment: @ratchetfreak For languages that do require these end keywords, that's a good point. Not all of them do, though, and almost all of the ones that don't need it, still implement it.

Comment: @Luc: C-derived languages indeed only support if/else with no specific elseif construct. So clearly elseif is not needed with C style syntax. Elseif is needed in some other languages for purely syntactic purposes, it does not introduce any new semantics beyond if/else.

Answer (score 11):

It it typically **not** possible to answer the question why a language (on any language) *doesn't* support a certain feature. Unless the feature explicitly was considered and rejected by the language designers, the explanation might very well be that nobody ever considered it in the first place. The feature you suggest is so obscure that I would consider it very likely that nobody ever thought seriously about it, so nobody ever made the conscious decision to not support it.

The feature will be difficult to implement in C-style languages, since in these languages an `if`-statement with multiple branches is really just a nested chain of simple `if`/`else` statements. Your proposal would require a different parsing logic, since the last branch should "know about" all the previous branches.

Furthermore, the semantics are non-obvious. `If`/`else` is simple - based on a condition *either* one branch is executed or the other. But in your construct, a condition could mean that *two* branches are executed. So what if there is a return in the first branch?

Lastly, the utility is limited. You avoid writing `(condition1 and condition2)` - but only this exact combination is special-cased. If you have a complex `if` with many cases, there are multiple combinations you might want to handle, but only one is special cased. And you need to read all the `if`-conditions to be clear what exactly is the "invisible" case, so it doesn't improve readability.

I understand you want to keep DRY, but I don't really think it is a violation of DRY to explicitly state `if (condition1 and condition2)`, since this particular combination does not appear anywhere else. You are not repeating any information. At best you are saving some keystrokes, but that is not the same as DRY, which is concerned about repetition of information, not repetition of keystrokes.

Comment: *"the explanation might very well be that nobody ever considered it in the first place"* Indeed, that might be. I'm asking to see whether there is anything stupid about the idea before I propose to include it in a certain language. I personally come across it often enough that I think it's worth considering.

Comment: I wouldn't call it stupid, but I think the utility is very limited compared to the cost of a new control structure, and I think it would lead to more obscure code at least as often as it would improve clarity.

Comment: I'm amused at how this answer keeps growing... I have to take issue with your newest comments about DRYness. It seems to me that repeating the condition is a repetition of information. In particular, if I want to add a new condition, I will have it to in two places which indicates to me that the code isn't dry.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: If you have an `if(condition1)...` and later an `if(condition1 and condition2)...` this is not a repetition of information, since these are different expressions.

Comment: condition1 is the same expression, repeated twice. That isn't different expressions.

Comment: Furthermore, I really don't think that whether or not the same expression is repeated is the same thing as whether or not information is repeated. I may repeat an express (say checking if I'm running a unix-like system) in numerous places, but each place is a different piece of information for what happens on a unix-like system. I could also use different expressions to check for the same information (say lots of different ways to check for a unix-like system) to do the same thing in lots of situations, and that would be a duplication information but not expression.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: I assumed `condition1`in the example was a variable, but if it is pseudocode for a complex expression then obviously it is violating DRY. But you use local variables to avoid repeating complex expression.

Comment: Here is an example gist: https://gist.github.com/winstonewert/4e176f150cbc627ac4b8, can you show how you would use local variables to write this code?

Comment: The any block is active if any of the if blocks fired, not if all of them fired

Comment: Regarding your gist.  The pattern I see for this is to return true at each of the successful branches but return false if none of the branches fired.  outside of the function place your "I did it" vs "is unsupported" blocks.  It is DRY, easy to read and doesn't introduce any new symbols.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: You use local variable like: `isPosix = os.name == 'posix'` to avoid repeating expressions.

Answer (score 3):

This could be handled with a boolean

```
bool isResult4Needed= true;
if (condition1) {
    result1;
} else if (condition2) {
    result2;
} else {
    result3;
    isResult4Needed= false;
}
if (isResult4Needed) {
    result4;
}
```

This construct is more flexible than a language feature like `any`, because it also handles all of the other cases like "I want to do X if I went down branch A B C or D, but I want to do Y if I went down branch E F G or H" using the exact same approach.  A language addition would have to be far more complicated, and would likely end up with the same amount of extra syntax.

Comment: While still introducing an extra variable, I think this is the most concise and reasonable of answers besides the one I currently intend to accept as answer. Upvote for that.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me rephrase I understand your case:
If condition 1 or 2, you want to also run result 4 right?

```
if condition1{
  result1
  result4
}elseif condition2{
  result2
  result4
}else{
  result3
}
```

Or you can do:

```
if condition1{
  result1
}elseif condition2{
  result2
}else{
  result3
  return
}
result4
```

Comment: The latter is the only alternative that does not require me to write the same thing multiple times (DRY), but of course only works if it's in a function by itself. This is usually not the case.

Comment: @Luc us a goto then. Or put the thing in a function.

Comment: @Luc if it gets much bigger you should consider extracting the function. I don't see how you get what you want without adding a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are cases of constructs in languages that are somewhat related to this. Python, in particular, has a couple of examples:

We have else block for for loops:

```
for item in alpha:
    if test(item):
       break
else:
    print "Not Found!"
```

And the else block for exceptions:

```
try:
   something_that_might_fail()
except:
   print "Something went wrong!"
else:
   print "Everything is fine"
```

There are related in the sense that they introduce an extra block to a control structure, like what you are proposing. Certainly, what you propose could be added in the same fashion.

On the actual merits of the proposal, I think the construct isn't flexible enough. Your proposal handles this case:

```
if condition1:
   handler1()
   post_handler()
elif condition2:
   handler2()
   post_handler()
else:
   no_handler()
```

But what if I wanted to do this:

```
if condition1:
   pre_handler()
   handler1()
elif condition2:
   pre_handler()
   handler2()
else:
   no_handler()
```

Or maybe this:

```
if condition1: 
   with transaction():
      handler1()
elif condition2:
   with transaction():
      handler2()
else:
   no_handler()
```

So your proposal seems to handle some of the cases that might arise. As such it doesn't seem to provide much value from a language design standpoint.

In current languages, I might implement this situation like:

```
# actually, in my case this part is almost always a lookup, not a list
# of conditions. YMMV.
if condition1:
   handler = handler1
elif condition2:
   handler = handler3
else:
   handler = None

if handler is not None:
   handler()
   post_handler()
else:
   no_handler()
```

Or

```
for handler in handlers:
    if handler.condition():
       handler.act()
       break
else:
    no_handler()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the primary issue with the construct as you've defined it is that you're logically separating each of the `if` and `else if` blocks from the `else` block. This probably makes sense when you're very specifically checking a string and performing a command, like this:

```
if myString.equals("loadPotatoes") {
  loadPotatoes();
else if myString.equals("firePotatoes") {
  firePotatoes();
any {
  cleanPotatoes(); // whether we load or fire, clean out old potatoes
}
else {
  throw "Did not recognize command " + myString;
}
```

But in this case, the semantic similarity of the `String.equals` comparison is entirely the programmer's choosing. In a general case, you could be checking "if command equals etc, else if `database.errorreportingserver.isconnected()`, else if `areGUIErrorAlertsEnabled`" and such.

If anything, this is a good reason to move away from repeating a particular code operation like `String.Equals` (as you said, DRY) to a genuine reusable loop or dedicated construct for it. For instance, in my example, you'd have a readonly `string->Action` map showing a relation between command names and a lambda function, for which you perform a lookup, and then either do that action and then `cleanPotatoes()`, or when the map finds nothing, do something else.

As others said, this is also a bit of an edge case, and because languages tend to avoid adding keywords or special rules (I could see this unintentionally taking effect against a syntax error for what's meant to be a basic `if/else`) the value proposition isn't high.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're trying to get to the idea of [Railway-oriented programming](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/). This isn't very well-supported in most object-oriented languages, but you can do it with the addition of a `Maybe`, `Either`, or `Result` container.

For example, if we have four functions that all return a `Maybe` or `Nothing`, you could do something like this:

```
if condition1:
  result = functionA()
else if condition2:
  result = functionB()
else:
  result = functionC()

return result.or(defaultValue)
```